# Only assignment, call, increment, decrement, and new object expressions can be used as a statement in mvc

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, compiler-errors, controller

I'm trying to get the amount from one of my tables in DB by using inline if in my controller

```
    public ActionResult IfPaid(int id)
    {
        Ref_ViewModel = new View_model.View_Model();
        Ref_ViewModel.GetAllCustomers(id).Any(p => p.Paid == false) ? RedirectToAction("Pay", "Account") : RedirectToAction("Download");
    }
```

I get this error in the last line

> Only assignment, call, increment, decrement, and new object expressions can be used as a statement

How can we fix this?

Comment: Please note that the model-view-controller tag is for questions about the pattern. There is a specific tag for the ASP.NET-MVC implementation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should add a return statement:

```
public ActionResult IfPaid(int id)
{
    Ref_ViewModel = new View_model.View_Model();
    return Ref_ViewModel.GetAllCustomers(id).Any(p => p.Paid == false)
         ? RedirectToAction("Pay", "Account")
         : RedirectToAction("Download");
}
```

As the error message says, the ternary operator on its own is not a statement. It can be part of another statement - e.g. return statement as above, or assignment statement

```
   int value = condition ? 0 : 42;
```

Further reading: [Statements (C# Programming Guide)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/articles/csharp/programming-guide/statements-expressions-operators/statements)

Comment: i Can't believe that this was making the problem ,tnx in advance